# Issue deleting duplicate records in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, duplicates

so I seem to be having a moment and can't figure out why certain dups in a table are not getting deleted. I have a test table called QUERY that has names, addresses, DOB's, phones, etc. I am looking to delete the dups, but want to keep the most recent record (preferable but the below code doesn't represent that) where the phone is not empty. My code below just isn't working always giving 0 results. An example of a row would be:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
|   first,last,DOB,address,city,state,phonenumber,validitydate   |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| steve,smith,19710922, 123 Here St, Miami, FL,9545551212,201902 |
| steve,smith,19710922, 123 Here St, Miami, FL,,202009           |
| steve,smith,19710922, 123 Here St, Miami, FL,9545551212,201802 |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

```
WITH Records AS
(  
SELECT lastname, firstname, address, state, dateofbirth, phonenumber
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY lastname, firstname, address, state, dateofbirth, phonenumber order by validitydate) AS RecordInstance
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY lastname, firstname, address, state, dateofbirth, phonenumber order by
    CASE
        WHEN phonenumber ='' THEN 0
        WHEN phonenumber IS NOT NULL THEN 1
        Else 0
        END) as [ToInclude]
FROM query 
)
    
delete
FROM records
WHERE
    RecordInstance > 1
    and ToInclude = 0
```

Anyone see anything I am doing wrong?? Thanks in advance

Comment: `ToInclude` is never going to be `0`, when its value is derived from `ROW_NUMBER` (which starts at `1`).

Comment: So I did just replace ToInclude from = 0 to >1, but did leave a duplicate where the phone was still blank. In a perfect world, the first record with the phone intact should only remain.

Comment: You can do a `select * from Records where.....` to check if the field `ToInclude` get the (desired) correct value.

Comment: Because the row with the must recent validity has a value of `''` for the phonenimber, @Sal . If that isn't correct, you don't want to most recent row,

Answer (score 0):

I think here is what you want to do :

```
SELECT 
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY lastname, firstname, address, state, dateofbirth, phonenumber order by validitydate) AS RecordInstance
   ,COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY lastname, firstname, address, state, dateofbirth, phonenumber) DUPS
FROM QUERY
WHERE DUPS > 2 
AND RecordInstance = 1
AND phonenumber <> '' -- maybe? if you really don't want to delete duplicates with no phone number
```

Comment: hmm count requires an argument

Comment: yeah , missed *

Answer (score 0):

If your required result is to delete all the duplicate records where phone number is not null or empty then you can try below query:

```
WITH Records AS
(  
SELECT lastname, firstname, address, state, dateofbirth, phonenumber
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY lastname, firstname, address, state, dateofbirth, phonenumber order by validitydate) AS RecordInstance
    
FROM query where phonenumber<>'' and phonenumber is not null
)
    
delete
FROM records
WHERE
    RecordInstance > 1
```

Comment: this is close but still keeps the record that has no phone and acts like a regular dedupe on records with same phone

Comment: Do you want to remove all the rows with no phone number?

Comment: Or you want to delete all the rows with same lastname, firstname, address, state, dateofbirth, phonenumber and blank phone number.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
RecordInstance = ROW_NUMBER()   OVER(PARTITION BY LastName, FirstName,  Address, City, DateOfBirth ORDER BY PhoneNumber DESC, ValidityDate)
```